# the order C++ global variable destruct?

Tags: c++, destructor

I got two global variable:

```
static mutex m;
static object o;
```

and the destruct |o| need to use |n|

```
~object() {
  auto_lock(&m);
}
```

but, I found that some times the |m| has been destructed.
I wonder the order of global variable destruct?

Comment: "I found that [it] has been destructed". How did you found that?

Comment: `struct MyStruct{ mutex m; object o; }` and then a global MyStruct instance and you're set. However, I doubt you *really* need that global

Comment: Yeah, My fault for not said clear. I am working a exist project. There many codes. So I was trying to figure out the c++ destruct mechanism. And then I will try think about the solution.

Comment: @JBL I found will I exit the program.It　will be crash at the destruct of object. And the error is that the mutex is not valid. And I have  many objects destruct before exit, so the mutex can't be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destructors are always called in reverse order of construction. But if both variables are located in different compilation units then its hard to tell which will get constructed first. But if your variables are located in single compilation unit then you should be safe.

References:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: I beg for some nice reference. Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Static objects are destructed in reverse order of construction BUT there's is very difficult (and almost impossible) to control that order.

If you need more control you may want to wrap them inside some structure.

```
struct EnsureOrder {
    mutex m;
    object o;
};

static EnsureOrder wrapper;
```

If those two objects are in the same `.cpp` file I'm pretty sure the object should be constructed in the order they were defined.

Comment: it makes no sense making m and o static, that will have the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference count and self destruction approach - create `m` and `o` on heap and wrap them into some kind of reference counting and destruction container. So, when you create `o` you should increment reference count on `m`, and when you destruct `o` you should decrement reference count on `m`. Thus, you can control the order of construction/destruction of your global variables. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved through dependency injection (i.e. declare the mutex as the first thing in main and pass it to the constructor of object).